# Automatically add a number to a HashMap<Integer, String>

Tags: java

Lets say I have

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> matchup = new HashMap<>();
```

instead of manually adding the key how would I be able to add a number in order 1 through 100 so let.

Lets say I have 3 users when they click a button called **add me to quene** they get added to the quene with a Integer key defined by there position in the quene.

So if the first user clicks the button he would automatically be assign the key value 1 with a string.

So if the second user clicks the button he would automatically be assign the key value 2 with a string.

So if the third user clicks the button he would automatically be assign the key value 3 with a string.

etc;

Comment: Use a counter variable, and increment it every time you add an element to the map?

Comment: If the key to map is a straight index, then what you've got is probably better suited for ArrayList that a Map.

Comment: In order to avoid concurrency problem use the timestamp value; it's much safer rather than an integer progressive. The alternative is as @JBNizet says a counter variable but don't forget to mark the method to get this variable synchronized!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments for VA31 reply - you can improve your code.Just make it thread safe.

You can try code below:

```
public class Click {

private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
private Map<Integer, String> matchup = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void onClick(String input) {
    matchup.put(counter.incrementAndGet(), input);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is guaranteed to be threadsafe? The keys won't collide themselves but could the hashes (attempting to write into the same hashbucket at the same time) either now or in some possible future / alternative implementation of HashMap? If not ConcurrentHashMap would be better.

Answer (score 1):

The following code might help:

```
public class Click {

    private static int counter = 0;
    public static HashMap<Integer, String> matchup = new HashMap<>();

    public void onClick(String input) {
        matchup.put(counter++, input);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This code is not thread safe.If you will run in in parallel - you will notice, that there will be leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable that will be used as counter :

```
public static Integer nextId = 0;
...
...
matchup.put(++nextId, "any string...");
```